# Jquery UI confirm dialog is being displayd perfectly in fiddle but not on website

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

The following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FyF9/) works ok but when I try the same code on my website there is no border at all it is transparent and is all over the place.

I have tried to disable all the css and inherited css from firebug but it still looks the same.

Maybe it's not the existing css but rather it needs some css to be defined for the dialog and maybe fiddle includes it automatically but not quite sure...

```
$("#click").click(function (event) {

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes go ahead": function () {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Are you including jquery UI css after your main css? If not then it may cause an issue like what you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.import jquery-ui.js file to your page.
>   2.import jquery-ui.css file as well.
>   3.Check your code reside in `$(document).ready(function(){});`
>   4.If none of them work,open browser console,make a note of the error and comment below..